# Access a list of all the installed features on a site using javascript

Tags: csom, jsom, features

I am trying to find a list of all the features on my SharePoint 2013 cloud site using JavaScript.

When I get the context to the site I don't see `FeatureDefinitions` as part of the site object (`SP.ClientContext(url).get_site()`) or web object (`SP.ClientContext(url).get_web()`).

I can retrieve all of the active features for both using `get_features()`, but this is not what I am looking for.

Am I looking at the wrong object? Is this not doable in JavaScript?

Comment: So you are looking to find all the available features (both activated and not activated)? Is my understading correct?

Comment: Correct. any solution that is installed on the collection.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no way to retrieve the list of available features from the client side, but you could extract this information from `Features` page as demonstrated below:

```
function getFeatureDefinitions(scope){       
   var url = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('ManageFeatures.aspx');
   if(scope == 'Site')
     url+= '?Scope=Site';
   return $.get(url)
          .then(function(data){
              var featureDefs = $(data).find('th#FeatureIcon').closest('table').children('tbody').children('tr').not(':first').map(function() {
                  var featureDef = {};
                  featureDef.title = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(1) td").text().trim(); 
                  featureDef.desc = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(2) td").text().trim();
                  featureDef.id = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").find('div').attr('id');
                  return featureDef;
              }); 
              return featureDefs.toArray(); 
          });

}
```

**Usage**

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
   getFeatureDefinitions('Site')
   .done(function(featureDefs){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(featureDefs,null,2));
   });

});
```

Comment: What if SP site layout changes? :)